# Angular2 - is TopicView's route a child of ForumView's route?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am trying to implement a small forum using Angular. My question is regarding routes. Suppose I have a component called ForumView which displays basic information (title, post count, last activity) about all the topics in specific a forum. This component is associated with route 'forum/:forumId'. Now, each of the topics' title redirects (EDIT: if the user clicks it) to a TopicView (in which the topic's contents (posts) will be displayed) by navigating to the route 'forum/:forumId/topic/:topicId'.

Should TopicView be a child route of ForumView in this case? My confusion is because I've read something that the parent component should actually have a `<router-outlet>` tag to display its children. Is this really necessary? Can't I just use the same `<router-outlet>` tag to display the children, just as I did with its parent?